# why does Solr not return any result on "suits" when there is a document that containing the word "Suits"

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search

I have a little problem with my Solr search engine. It does not return any result when I search on the word "suits". I'm 100% sure that it exists a document that are containing the word "Suits". I can however search for the word "suit" and the result containing "suits" ends up.

My schema:

```
<schema name="hello" version="1.3">
    <types>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
        <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
    </types>
    <fields>
        <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
        <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="profileMiniature" type="string" stored="true" required="true"/>
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <defaultSearchField>title</defaultSearchField>
</schema>
```

my query is `"title:$q*^2 description:$q*"`.

Comment: I would think the stemmer would make the two queries identical... try it without the wildcards, maybe?

Comment: you mean `*`? Already tried it and it worked! But how can I partially search for words without using `*`?

Comment: Try using analysis page to know how its indexed and searched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search with wildcards disables the analysis (as described [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Analyzers)).

To match `suit` with `suits`, you need [stemming](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Stemming) and not wildcards.  Using wildcards will anyway not work if your data has `suit` and the query is `suits`.

Could you provide some more information - maybe a use-case which explains why you need wildcards?  It will help us come up with a better solution to your problem.